# postgres/sqlalchemy/python: group-by/max in union query?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sqlalchemy, max, union

I'm using sqlalchemy in python with a postgres database.

I want to perform a union query from two tables, upon which I want to select the rows with the maximum of a column with a common key. I have not been able to figure out how to make this work in sqlalchemy.

Suppose I have a table object for table `users` and another table object for table `orders`.

I know how to define this union query:

```
union_query = union(
  select([users.c.email,  users.c.timestamp]),
  select([orders.c.email, orders.c.timestamp])
)
```

However, in some cases, there might be common `email` columns with differing `timestamp` values. In this case, I want the result to show the largest `timestamp` for any given `email`.

For example, suppose the `users` table contains this data:

```
email   | timestamp
--------| ---------
a@b.com | 00:00:00
c@d.com | 02:03:04
e@f.com | 10:10:10
```

... and suppose the `orders` table contains this data:

```
email   | timestamp
--------| ---------
a@b.com | 12:12:12
c@d.com | 01:01:01
q@r.com | 09:09:09
```

I want the results of my union-based query to be as follows ...

```
email   | timestamp
--------| ---------
a@b.com | 12:12:12
c@d.com | 02:03:04
e@f.com | 10:10:10
q@r.com | 09:09:09
```

I haven't been able to come up with the proper combinations of `group_by()`, `func.max()`, and other sqlalchemy functions to use with my `union_query` in order to generate this query.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I came up with the answer. An alias is needed, and `union_query` needs to be used as a subquery.

Do any of you see anything wrong with this, or perhaps a more efficient way to do it?

```
union_query = union(
  select([users.c.email,  users.c.timestamp]),
  select([orders.c.email, orders.c.timestamp])
).alias('uq_alias')

query = select(
          [union_query.c.email, func.max(union_query.c.timestamp)]
        ).group_by(union_query.c.email)
```

... and then simply execute `query`.

Comment: where `updated_at` column came from? should it be named `timestamp`?

Comment: Yes, `updated_at` is incorrect. I have corrected it. I constructed this example from a more complicated piece of actual code which used other variable names, and I missed one of them.